# Did Oracle remove the Java System Preference in macOS?

Tags: macos, mojave, java, system-settings

I recently updated my Java install on macOS 10.14.4 from Java 10 to Java 11, and the Java System Preference pane disappeared after Java updated. I updated Java again on a different Mac running the same macOS version (10.14.4), and again, the Java System Preference disappeared. I check to see if Java was still installed using `$: java -version`, and this is the output I get:

```
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

This tells me Java is still installed.

Did Oracle discontinue the use of the Java System Preference pane in macOS? I couldn't find anything in Oracle's documentation that would indicated they did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the Java Control Panel was removed in Java 11.

> Please note that the Java Control Panel, which was used for configuring the deployment technologies, has also been removed along with the shared system JRE (but not the server JRE) and the JRE Auto Update mechanism

[JDK 11 Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#JDK-8185077)

Check out the answer [karma4917](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10431118/karma4917) provided on Stack Overflow:
[MacOS Java Control Panel Missing on Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53176853/6651671)

Comment: Some further information: the control panel was mainly used to control the Java WebStart and Applet environments. With JWS removed and applets deprecated for removal, it lost its main reason to exist.